# "train your dogs commands" It seems to sound bad to me

Tags: vocabulary

"train your dogs commands"
It seems to sound bad to me. Am I right? I've seen this on the Internet.

Comment: Where on the internet.  The internet is a big place.  Add the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one use on the "internet" in a review of Sims Pets, by an anonymous reviewer dated 2006 (not the most carefully written form of English).  .  . It's wrong, should be "teach".

Unlike "train",  teach takes two objects "teach your dog commands". With "train" you'd have to say "Train your dog to obey commands".